# How to replace javascript ajax with jQuery ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**What i want to do?**
I am thinking of changing javascript ajax to jQuery ajax. It seems shorter, and i saw many people using it, but i can't really get it working.

**What i have so far?**
I have an element:
`<li id="unique_id" onmousedown="check_element(event, this)">1</li>`
When i click on the element, it check which key has been pressed, if its mouse1 then checks background of the element. If element has no background color it changes it to "red" and add id of the element to MySQL database using ajax.
If it had red background already (meaning it was added before) it uses ajax to delete it from database.

**Code**
Checking function

```
function check_element(evt, e){
    if(evt.which == 1){
        if(e.style.background == "") {
            e.style.background = "red";
            send_with_ajax("add", e);
        } else {
            e.style.background = "";
            send_with_ajax("delete", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Ajax (with javascript):

```
function send_with_ajax(action, e){
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } 
    xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax/send_calendar.php?data="+e.id+"&action="+action+"",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

send_calendar.php is nothing out of ordinary. Just grabs variables from `$_GET['']` and INSERTS or DELETES values from database. The thing is, how can i change this function to make it jQuery Ajax?

**What have i tried?**

```
function send_with_ajax(action, e){
    $.Ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "send_calendar.php",
        data: "data="+e.id+"&action="+action+"",
        success: function(msg){
            alert( "Data Saved: " + msg ); //never shows this alert
        }
    });
}
```

also i get error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)} has no method 'Ajax'`

PS. Never worked with jQuery Ajax before, so i have NO CLUE what i am doing wrong.

Comment: It's `$.ajax` (lowercase `a`). Other than that, it looks fine.

Comment: Also, try using the shortcut methods `$.get()` and `$.post()` if you already know what type of AJAX call you will be making. i.e. `$.ajax("send_calendar.php", "data="+e.id+"&action="+action, function(data) { alert("Data Saved: " + data); });`

Comment: `PS. Never worked with jQuery Ajax before, so i have NO CLUE what i am doing wrong.` Then the very first thing you should do is read the [**jQuery ajax documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Also, note that AJAX simply stands for Asynchronous JavaScript and XML. It's not "jQuery AJAX". jQuery simply has encapsulated the logic for making AJAX calls. It's still Javascript, just as jQuery is still just Javascript.

Comment: jquery ajax should manage the params data for you in a get request

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) (case-sensitive), not `$.Ajax`.

Also notice, the `data` option accepts an object as input and `$.ajax` will do the parameter serialization by itself.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "ajax/send_calendar.php",
    data: {
        "data" : e.id,
        "action": action
    },
    success: function(msg) {
        alert("Data Saved: " + msg);
    }
});
```

There also exist shorthand methods for GET and POST requests, [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) and [`.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) respectively.

Comment: Please note the `$.get()` and `$.post()` shortcut methods as well.

Comment: @crush, added for completeness

Comment: thanks! =] They are great for this sort of thing when the HTTP Request type is static.

Answer (score -2):

If you're going to use jQuery, also make sure to have the correct wrapper code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
        url: "send_calendar.php",
        data: "data="+e.id+"&action="+action+"",
        success: function(msg){
            alert( "Data Saved: " + msg ); //never shows this alert
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Totally wrong, that's not what `$(document).ready` is for. If you don't need to access the DOM, you don't need `$(document).ready`, and it's **definitely** not "necessary for jQuery to trigger your codeblock". All it actually does is make sure that the DOM is available to the function you give it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I need to read more about its use.